# How to convert a column in dataframe from date format "MDDYY" to date format "YYYYMMDD"

Tags: r, data-analysis

This is the first dataset's date format, it is in "YYYYMMDD" format

[image: This is the first dataset's date format, it is in "YYYYMMDD" format]

This is the second dataset's date format, it is in "MDDYY" format
[image: This is the second dataset's date format, it is in "MDDYY" format]

How could I convert the dates reported in the second dataset to the format used in the first (YYYYMMDD)
I got stuck on this question and my code doesn't make sense.
Please give me some example for this, the date needs to stay in "as.data.frame

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can specify a date format in `as.POSIXct`. For example

```r
x <- c("19900104")
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y%m%d")
```

and

```r
x <- c("22601", "110101")
as.POSIXct(ifelse(nchar(x) == 5, paste0("0", x), x), format = "%m%d%y")
```

`as.POSIXct` can be used on an entire column vector like so

```r
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = ...)
```

Comment: Change your second block to include `x <- c("22601", "110101")` and see that it incorrectly deduces the second year to be 2010. I suggest replacing your paste0 with `paste0(strrep("0", pmax(0, 6-nchar(x))), x)` (or some contrived `ifelse` with similar effect).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your review. I made the changes you propose.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to parse the date is to use the [`mdy()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html) from package `lubridate`.

```
mdy(22601)
# [1] "2001-02-26"
```

```
df$date <- mdy(df$date)
```